# Increment value within range until corresponding cell value increases by specified amount

Tags: excel, increment, vba

I have this problem to be sorted out. Namely, I need the code that will place the same values in the range until corresponding cells value increases by one. Once it does the value needs to be incremented by 0.2 and place incremented number until again the corresponding cell value is higher by one

```
Sub Button4_Click()


  range1 = Sheets(3).Range("g2").End(xlDown).Row
  range2 = "g2:g" & range1





   For i = 2 To range1

   If Cells(i, 7).Value <= 360 Then

   Cells(i, 8) = 60

   range3_n = Cells(i, 8).Row

   End If
   Next





  j = 0.2
  k = 1
  For i = range3_n To range1



  If Cells(i, 7) > 360 And Cells(i, 7) <= (360 + k) And Cells(i, 7) <= (360 + 
  100) Then

  Cells(i, 8) = 60 + (k * j)
  k = k + 1
  End If
  Next

   MsgBox ("END")    


   End Sub
```

Comment: I don't exactly understand what you are trying to accomplish based on your code. So maybe you can help me understand:

1) You have a range, `G2:G[lastrow]`, with random values. Can you explain what these values are
2) You then check all those values, and if they meet your criteria, you set the column H equal to 60 (every cell).  Nowhere here do you do any incrementing by 1, you are just setting a solid value of 60.

What range are you trying to set to +1, and what are the values prior. And once they are +1 you then need to add .2 to those same values? So now it's 60.2?

Comment: 1) `G2:G[lastrow]`  contains time in minutes. 2) The first part of code fills in the cells with value 60 (temperature) until it reaches time of 360 minutes. then I need the code to increment value 60 by 0.2 every minute until minute 460. Therefore for the range containing all the values between 360-361 code should fill in the values of 60.2. For 361-362 the value of 60.4, and so on.

Comment: I threw numbers, 1 through 460 in cells G2 through G461 and it appears to have worked exactly how you are asking.  I ran the macro, and it placed 60 all the way down.  Then from G361 (Value 361) through G460 (Value 460) the value incremented by .2 each cell, up until 80.  

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sijWG.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlfbC.png

Linked are two screenshots I took.  Are these the results you are trying to achieve? If not, can you please explain what is incorrect about the .2 incrementing you've already achieved?

Comment: The problem is that this works only if the minutes are integer numbers increasing by one each row. My data is decimals:  https://ibb.co/bwN42v

Comment: Okay, one more question then:

At `360.0`, `360.1`, `360.2`, `360.3`, `etc.`, the value should remain at 60.  And then at `361.0`, `361.1`, `361.2`, `etc.`, the value should remain 60.2?  So you _ONLY_ want the .2 increment to occur when the value in `G2:G[lastrow]` increases by one full integer?

Comment: Yes. That is correct: 0.2 increment should occur when the value in `G2:G[lastrow]` increases by one full integer and then fill in that value into all cells until again in `G2:G[lastrow]` there is increase by one full integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, and keeping the code structure the exact same as it is, an easy solution is adding a new IF Statement after your last one:

```
IF (Cells(i, 7) - Int(Cells(i, 7)) = 0) Then
```

The code should look like:

```
Sub Button4_Click()

range1 = Sheets(1).Range("g2").End(xlDown).Row
range2 = "g2:g" & range1

For i = 2 To range1
    If Cells(i, 7).Value <= 360 Then
        Cells(i, 8) = 60
        range3_n = Cells(i, 8).Row
    End If
Next

range3_n = range3_n + 1 'start at cell 361 instead
j = 0.2
k = 1

For i = range3_n To range1
  If Cells(i, 7) > 360 And Cells(i, 7) <= (361 + k) And Cells(i, 7) <= (360 + 100) Then
    If Int(Cells(i - 1, 7)) - Int(Cells(i, 7)) <> 0 Then
        Cells(i, 8) = 60 + (k * j)
        k = k + 1
    Else
        Cells(i, 8) = Cells(i - 1, 8)
        End If
  End If
Next i

MsgBox ("END")

End Sub
```

What this does is, it takes the value of the cell, subtracts the integer version of that value (360.1 = 360, 365.4 = 365, etc.) and ensures that equals zero.  Any decimal value > .0 will fail, and will not meet the criteria.

```
Example:
360.0 - 360 = 0 PASS
360.1 - 360 = .1 FAIL
360.4 - 360 = .4 FAIL
360.7 - 360 = .7 FAIL
361.0 - 361 = 0 PASS
```

Try it out and let me know.

Comment: Sorry but it does not work. There is no error but does not execute what it should, (I am guessing it does not meet criteria in `IF` statement) hence anything larger than 361 does not have value...

Comment: Can you show me a screenshot of your spreadsheet where Column G is around 360? On my sheet it goes `360.0 through 360.9` and the Cells to the right of those are 60.0.  When it hits 361, the value goes to 60.2, then it goes 361.1 and it remains 60.2.  Here's a screenshot of how it runs on mine: (https://i.stack.imgur.com/SERIo.png)

Comment: After I rounded column`G` values, this is what happened: https://ibb.co/iq8rFF  , still not right

Comment: I updated my response, and changed two things.  I changed your initial large IF Statement to: `And Cells(i, 7) <= (361 + k)` instead of 360, it just seems to work better.  I also took a different approach since I did not realize how far your decimals went. Do me a favor and run it without rounding first, then round if necessary.  I changed my IF Statement to `If Int(Cells(i - 1, 7)) - Int(Cells(i, 7)) <> 0 Then`.  What this does is, it takes the integer of the previous cell, and subtracts the current cell, if it doesn't equal 0 it increments by 0.2

Comment: Great job! It does work now as intended. Rep to you!